# Coloring Databar in Tablix WITH PALETTE (Reporting Services)

Tags: reporting-services, colors, ssrs-2008

I have a Report in **Reporting Services 2008 R2** with the following Dataset.

- Name    | Value
- Gabriel |   10
- Peter   |   8

---

I have the following *Tablix* with 3 Columns:

1. Name
2. Databar
3. Value

When I Run the report all the ***Databars*** are blue, However I wanted it to use the **Palette**.

Is there a way to call a Palette on an Expression or Code?

or a even better way to solve this?

Any help is appreciated.

**I Don't want to specify fixed colors, I want to call a pallete by code.**

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Custom Chart Color Palettes and Legends section of [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964128.aspx#moressrscharts_topic4).

Either way,

> To specify color values as constant or
>   expression-based values, click the
>   Series Style button on the appearance
>   properties for the data value in the
>   Edit Chart Value dialog box.

Comment: Yeah @Nat thats was something I would not like, to build my list of colours, I just wanted to get the palette ones. So I was thinking of a way to call the Palette Method for GetColourList(). I don't actually want a Custom Palette, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

In the Background box for the Databar, Select Expression and in the popup, put something like:
`=IIF(Parameters.Field.Value > 10, "Green", "Blue")`

FWIW, you can also nest IIF statements:
`"=IIF(Parameters.Field.Value > 10, "Green", IIF(Parameters.Field.Value < 2, "Red", "Yellow"))"`

EDIT:
Instead of:
`=IIF(Parameters.Field.Value > 10, "Green", "Blue")`
You could use the standard RGB color codes like:
`=IIF(Parameters.Field.Value > 10, "#00ff00", "#0000ff")`

Comment: that's not what I want I don't want to specify colours I want to call the palette by code. This article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964128.aspx#moressrscharts_topic4) already gave me a code that works, however it specifies fixed colours and I want to call a palette for colors.